# OPENQUERY with a variable in a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase, linked-server

How can I return a OpenQuery in SQL Server including a variable to a cursor?

```
DECLARE curMyCursor CURSOR FOR
    EXEC('SELECT *
          FROM OPENQUERY(SYBASE,
                ''SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyPrimaryKey=''''' + @Variable + ''''''')')
OPEN @ResultCrsr
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't.
put the open query result into a temp table and open a cursor on it.

but why do you need a cursor at all?? i'm sure there's a better way of doing things without it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use TSQL since you can't pass a variable into an `OPENQUERY`:

```
DECLARE sqlCMD VARCHAR(500);

SET @sqlCMD = 
   'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(PASON, ''SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE     MyPrimaryKey=''''' + @Variable + ''''''')')                    

EXEC (@sqlCMD);
```